# How to use a flag variable to break all the for-loops in spmd statement?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, broadcast, flags, spmd

I want to run multiple for-loops in Matlab, each for-loop have large number of iterations so I use spmd to run them in parallel. All the for-loops will be break out if in a for-loop, a criterion is met. How do I do this? Here is the simplified version of my program:

```matlab
    spmd
        flag = false;
        for i = 1:1:inf
            if flag == true
                break;
            end
            fprintf("x = %d, i = %d\n", labindex, i);
            if labindex == 7 && i == 111  %some condition is met
                flag = true;
            end
            flag = labBroadcast(?, flag); %I don't know how to broadcast flag to other workers
        end
    end
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/execute-simultaneously-on-multiple-data-sets.html): "The body of an spmd statement cannot contain break, continue, or return statements. Consider parfeval or parfevalOnAll instead of spmd, because you can use cancel on them."

Comment: @rahnema1 I am not using break statements right inside the spmd body. I use it inside a for-loop that is inside the spmd. So is it still legit?

Comment: My interpretation of the documentation may be incorrect. Possibly the correct wording of the documentation should be: "You cannot use break, continue, or return statements in the body of an spmd statement to break the program flow of the outside the spmd block."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `labBroadcast`, what you need to use here is `gop`. (In newer versions, this has been renamed to [`spmdReduce`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/spmdreduce.html). This will let you combine together all the local values of `flag` from each worker to see if any worker has set `flag` to `true`, like this:

```matlab
spmd
    for i = 1:inf
        flag = computeLocalFlag();
        % Combine all local values of flag using the "or" function
        % to see if any value is true:
        globalFlag = spmdReduce(@or, flag);
        if globalFlag
            break; % This is fine, because you're not trying to break out of spmd
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It works !! `gop` function works well with my program. Additional question: how do I print output texts on separated console windows for each worker?

Comment: In older releases of MATLAB, there was a multi-window "console" called `pmode` that could do this, but this eventually got retired.